# Mouse right click to visible the specific CSS class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to visible the specific css class when I click right button in mouse. If click left then its work as usual.
HTML code:

```
<table id="table-1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Row1</th>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Row3</th>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Row3</th>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Row4</th>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Row5</th>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>
        <td>info</td>           
    </tr>     
</tbody>
</table>
```

Css:

```
.hi_td {background-color:red}
.hi_th {background-color:#fcc}
```

JavaScript:

```
mdown=false; msel=[[],[]];
var funcfalse=function(){console.log('selsta');}
var getpos=function(o,i){var o=$(o); // get position of current cell               
msel[0][i]=o.parent().index();   // set row
msel[1][i]=o.index();            // set column
return msel;
}
var modsel=function(o){
var numsrt=function(a,b){return a-b;}
var r=getpos(o,1)[0].slice(0);r.sort(numsrt);
var c=       msel[1].slice(0);c.sort(numsrt);
$trs=$('#table-1 tbody tr');
$('td',$trs).removeClass('hi_td');
$trs.slice(r[0],r[1]+1).each(function(){
    $('td',this).slice(c[0]-1,c[1]).addClass('hi_td');});
$("#table-1 thead tr th").removeClass('hi_th')
    .slice(c[0],c[1]+1).addClass('hi_th');
$("#table-1 tbody tr th").removeClass('hi_th')
    .slice(r[0],r[1]+1).addClass('hi_th');    
}             
var hover=function(ev){ if (mdown) modsel(this); }
var mo=function(ev){ mdown=(ev.type=='mousedown')?1:0;
getpos(this,1-mdown);
if (mdown) modsel(this);
}
var $tbl = $("#table-1"),$tblHead = $("#table-1 thead tr");
$("tbody td",$tbl)
.on({"mousedown":mo,"mouseup":mo,"mouseenter":hover,"selectstart":funcfalse});
```

In following JsFiddle link I want to visible the red highlight for right click. Link:http://jsfiddle.net/RmAqP/34/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your fiddle the code works fine. Highlighting of the proper row/column occurs with either a right or left mouse click. I'm guessing that you also want to make it so that you do not have any right click context menu appearing and getting in the way so by adding

```
oncontextmenu="return false"
```

to the element that you want this functionality on you can accomplish that goal.

update to your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RmAqP/36/

edit: I run Chrome/Firefox regularly which is where this code works, but looking again this isn't compatible with IE, you didn't specify if browser mattered to you

Comment: Is there any solution of mouse right click function? I really want to visible my highlighted css when I right click on any highlighted cell.

Comment: Actually I need to visible total highlighted cells when mouse right click. For example: if {row-1,(col-1,col-2,col-3)} are highlighted and mouse right click on any highlighted cell, then total selected portion are not change.Only change when mouse left clicked.